# Combining two separate case statements in NetSuite Case Statements

Tags: netsuite, case-statement, saved-searches

I currently have two separate saved search columns for these two statements, and I'm hoping to combine them and list the data in just one column. I've tried OR AND, but the results then error out.

First Statement
Case when {item.custitem54} is null then {quantity} else null end

Second Statement
Case when {item.custitem54} = 'Yes' and {shipdate} between to_date('05/25/2020', 'MM/DD/YYYY') and to_date('12/25/2020', 'MM/DD/YYYY') then {quantity} else null end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have multiple WHEN in a case statement. The first matched WHEN determines the result unless it gets to the ELSE.

```
Case when {item.custitem54} = 'Yes' 
          and {shipdate} between date '2020-05-25' and date '2020-12-25' then {quantity} 
     when {item.custitem54} is null then {quantity} 
     else null 
end
```